# form submission throws unhandled error event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

Good day am trying to create a form that registers a user into the system by only using a login form. Creating a user ,matching passwords is working but at the first if statement where it checks if the fields are not empty the application breaks and it gives an error: *"events.js:292
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"*

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var username = req.body.username;
        var pass = req.body.password;
        var salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        var hashedPasswd = await bcrypt.hash(pass, salt);
        //console.log(username+" "+pass,hashedPasswd);
        if (!username || !pass) {
            res.send(`Check fields!`);
            
        }
        newUser.findOne({/////////////check if user exists/////////////
            nick: username
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (!user) {
                var addUser = new newUser({
                    nick: username,
                    pass: hashedPasswd
                });
                addUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) res.send("Something went wrong with the save");
                });
                res.send("User added");
            } else if(user)  {
                let bool = bcrypt.compareSync(pass, user.pass);
                if (bool == false) {
                    res.send("Invalid password");
                } else {
                    res.send("Correct");
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending `res.send()` two times.

I think here is the problem:

```
addUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err) res.send("Something went wrong with the save");
});
res.send("User added");
```

Comment: no its not send two times..first time is for the error and the second time is when the user is added to db..also the problem its not there..

Comment: Okay, I had the same problem, and I was sending `res. send()` multiple times. :)

Comment: it crashes after the first res.send().... if there is anyway to come out from try catch